# insert string which includes quotes in oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sql-insert, clob

How can I insert string which includes quotes in oracle?
my code is

```
INSERT INTO TIZ_VADF_TL_MODELS (name)
VALUES ('xxx'test'yy');
```

if I use

```
INSERT INTO TIZ_VADF_TL_MODELS (name)
VALUES ("xxx'test'yy");
```

I get identifier is too long error because xxx'test'yy is clob.

how can I do that?

thx.

Comment: You cannot use double-quotes ("). Use two single-quotes(')

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can also use the ['alternative quoting mechanism' syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#i42617):

```
INSERT INTO TIZ_VADF_TL_MODELS (name)
VALUES (q'[xxx'test'yy]');
```

The pair of characters immediately inside the first set of quotes, `[]` in this case, delimit the quoted text; single quotes within those do not have to be escaped. Of course, you can't then have `]'` within the string itself, but you can pick your own delimiters so that can be avoided if it's going to be an issue; `]` on its own would still be OK.

This can be simpler than making sure single quotes are escaped, which can get a bit messy, or at least hard to read and debug.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/311d7/1).

Comment: great answer. I also learned sqlfiddle.com  from u:) thx my friend!

Answer (score 13):

Try escaping the quotes:

```
'xxx''test''yy'
```

In SQL quotes can be escaped by adding another quote before them.

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes two times, instead of one double quotes.
for eg:

```
INSERT INTO TIZ_VADF_TL_MODELS (name)
VALUES ('xxx''test''yy');
```